# Unreal GAS: Influence of the GameplayEffect aggregator on gameplay attribute values

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-gameplay-ability-system

During analyzing the lifetime of a [GameplayEffect](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Gameplay/GameplayAbilitySystem/GameplayAttributesAndGameplayEffects) modifier and execution, I've stumbled across **attribute aggregators** or **GameplayEffect aggregators** (both terms are used in source code). These are used to evaluate modified attribute values (they are modified by GameplayEffects).

However, I don't understand how those aggregators influence the actual GameplayAbilitySystem attributes which are attached (as part of an AttributeSet) to the actor:

1. Does an *attribute/GameplayEffect aggregator* `FAggregator` influence the **base value** or the **current value** of a *gameplay attribute* `FGameplayAttributeData`?
2. Is the **base value** of an *attribute/GameplayEffect aggregator* `float FAggregator::BaseValue` related to the **base value** of a *gameplay attribute* `float FGameplayAttributeData::BaseValue`?

---

The vital components of **attribute/GameplayEffect aggregators** are

- so called *gameplay modifier evaluation channels* `EGameplayModEvaluationChannel`, which are used sequentially during value evaluation (the result of channel0 is passed as base value to channel1 etc)
- storing *modifiers* (with its magnitude, operation, tags and link to the applying *GameplayEffect*) in certain channels, which define the actual numerical evaluation

Those are used for doing the evaluation of

- a *final value*
- a *base value* by evaluating a final value in reverse, attempting to determine the *base value* from the modifiers (deprecated b/c GAS now has struct-based attributes - according to documentation)
- a *bonus value* (final value - base value)

(all of them are just return values of functions and are not member variables of the aggregator)

To notify other classes of an evaluation (or changes to the aggregator), two methods are used

1. [a delegate](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Delegates) `FOnAggregatorDirty` is broadcasted which contains a reference to the aggregator
2. every *GameplayEffect*, which is registered in the *AbilitySystemComponent*, updates the change to its affected attribute(s) (via `FActiveGameplayEffectsContainer::UpdateAggregatorModMagnitudes()`) by updating the aggregator `FAggregator` for the attribute (which is determined or set via `FindOrCreateAttributeAggregator()`) in `FAggregator::UpdateAggregatorMod()`)

I don't see, how one or both of those notification methods update the actual attribute values.

(The official documentation/source code as well as the excellent [GAS: Comprehensive Analysis](https://forums.unrealengine.com/community/community-content-tools-and-tutorials/116578-comprehensive-gameplayabilities-analysis-series) and [GAS and you](https://forums.unrealengine.com/community/community-content-tools-and-tutorials/110113-gameplayabilities-and-you) unfortunately don't shed light on GameplayEffect aggregators.)

Answer (score 2):

1. The *attribute/GameplayEffect aggregator* influences the **current value** of a *gameplay attribute*.
2. Partly yes. They are related in one direction: the base value of the *gameplay attribute* is used to set the base value of the *attribute/GameplayEffect aggregator*, but not the other way around. **The aggregator does not change the attribute base value**.

#### Explanation for (1)

I was on the right track by looking at the notification methods. In fact, both in conjunction are updating the *gameplay attribute*:

1. `FActiveGameplayEffectsContainer::FindOrCreateAttributeAggregator()` applies `UAbilitySystemComponent::OnAttributeAggregatorDirty()` to the `OnDirty` delegate (that delegate is executed when the aggregator changes as written in the question).
2. `OnAttributeAggregatorDirty()` calls `FActiveGameplayEffectsContainer::InternalUpdateNumericalAttribute()`, which calls
3. `UAbilitySystemComponent::SetNumericAttribute_Internal()`, which calls
4. `FGameplayAttribute::SetNumericValueChecked()`. That sets the **current value** of a gameplay attribute.

#### Explanation for (2)

The base value of the *attribute/GameplayEffect aggregator* is set only using the *gameplay attribute* base value `FGameplayAttributeData::BaseValue` in:

- `FActiveGameplayEffectsContainer::OnAttributeAggregatorDirty()`
- `FActiveGameplayEffectsContainer::SetAttributeBaseValue()`

The base value of the *gameplay attribute* is set by:

- `UAttributeSet::InitFromMetaDataTable()`
- `FActiveGameplayEffectsContainer::SetAttributeBaseValue()`

In both functions, the attribute base value has no relation to the base value of the aggregator.